# Not able to find property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a very simple local setup for VueJS and am having problems running a simple example that shows how raw HTML can be output. I'm not including link to JS Fiddle because I want to make it work on local setup only, and sometimes my examples work on JS Fiddle but not on local machine.

Anyway, here's the html code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <!-- Doesn't work! -->
    <p>{{ link }}</p>
    <!-- This works! -->
    <p v-html>{{ link }} </p> 
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's my app.js file:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            link: '<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>'
        }
    });
});
```

Now when I load the window, I get twice the following error:

`[Vue warn]: Property or method "link" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. (found in <Root>)`.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this one and see if it works as required. I moved the scripts after the body.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <!-- Doesn't work! -->
    <p>{{ link }}</p>
    <!-- This works! -->
    <p v-html>{{ link }} </p> 
  </div>
</body>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, sir! Works now. But why is it so when I've used the `load` event? Or should I have wrapped it inside jQuery's `$(document).ready`?

Comment: If you do use jQuery then it will be better to use it with doc ready. But I found it better to use the scripts after the body without load event or doc ready. You might see the {{link}} flashing for sometime at times. In that case just use the [v-clock] directive.
https://medium.com/vuejs-tips/v-cloak-45a05da28dc4